# iPhone SDK 4.0 Phone locked tool

Tags: ios4

Is there going to be a way with the 4.0 SDK to create a tool similar to Pandora(which was demoed today), so when the phone is locked, I can manipulate my app? So basically if my app was running, and my phone locks I don't have to unlock the phone to toggle something for the app?

Comment: iPhone OS 4.0 is still under NDA, so you'll probably have much better luck asking this on the Apple developer support forums.

https://devforums.apple.com/community/iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As kubi said, it's still under NDA. I would look into those API's that were publicly announced though. (The multitasking stuff.) I'm sure it's possible. Pandora did it in the demo, right?